# NetLogo: Routing

Tags: routes, netlogo, agent

I have NetLogo routing model and this is to go command for the truck which is transporting from warehouse to demand point based on the route which obtained from shortest path calculation. The truck is moving on a vertex.

```
to go-truck [route]
  let final_route route  
  let source item 0 final_route
  let destin []  
  set final_route remove-item 0 final_route  
  while [ length(final_route) > 0 ]
  [
    set destin item 0 final_route    
    let dex ( item destin x - item source x )
    let dey ( item destin y - item source y )    
    let deg ( atan dex dey - 360 )
    let dis ( [ link-length ] of link source destin  )    
    ask trucks [ set heading deg ]    
    let truck_speed 1    
    while[ dis >= truck_speed ]
    [
      ask trucks [ fd truck_speed ]
      set dis dis - truck_speed
      tick
    ]    
    ask trucks [ fd dis ]
    tick 
    set source destin
    set final_route remove-item 0 final_route
  ] 
end
```

I want to make the truck to change the route in between the trip. For example, initially the route is to point 1, 2, 3. When the time (ticks) is 100 and have been visiting point 1 and 2, there is a new point, point 4, so the truck can change the route to point 4. How to make the truck change the route? Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: If you add 4 to your route list, it should work